# select certains days from a date interval passing identifier 1,2,3 corresponding to days

Tags: sql, oracle

I´m trying to get days from a interval dates. Example: if i give an initial date of 21/06/2017 to 21/07/2017 & i wanna select just wednesdays & fridays from that date interval, how can i make it in oracle db?

appreciate help please!

updated..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CHAIRA"."PR_SAVEROOMS"
    (v_return OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,INIDATE IN VARCHAR2,ENDDATE IN VARCHAR2,DAYS IN NUMBER) AS
        v_error EXCEPTION;
        v_notificacion t_notificacion;
        -- variable del tipo varray[3] definida asi: [tipoNotificacion: |notificacion|notificacionPin|error|errorPin|advertencia|advertenciaPin|][tituloNotificacion][mensajeNotificacion]
   VARIABLE startDate varchar2;
   VARIABLE endDate varchar2;

BEGIN
:startDate := INIDATE;
:endDate := ENDDATE;

     SELECT day
FROM   ( 
  SELECT DATE TO_DATE(startDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + LEVEL - 1 as day
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY DATE TO_DATE(startDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + LEVEL - 1 <= DATE TO_DATE(endDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
)
WHERE day - TRUNC( day, 'IW' ) IN ( 2, 4 );

        v_notificacion := t_notificacion('notificacion','Información','Mensaje por defecto');
    OPEN v_return FOR SELECT v_notificacion(1) "_TIPO", v_notificacion(2) "_TITULO",v_notificacion(3)"_MENSAJE" FROM DUAL;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN v_error THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20333,v_notificacion(1)||'*'||v_notificacion(2)||'*'||v_notificacion(3)||'*');
            ROLLBACK;
 END;
```

I had updated according to MT0 suggestions & still cause an error, ..

I GIVE A FORMAT VARCHAR DATE AS DD/MM/YYYY...

Comment: add your table structure

Comment: what do you mean table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get all the dates:

```
SELECT DATE '2017-06-21' + LEVEL - 1 as day
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY DATE '2017-06-21' + LEVEL - 1 <= DATE '2017-07-21';
```

Then you just need to filter by Wednesdays and Fridays. For this you can use the difference between the day and the start of the iso-week, given by `TRUNC( day, 'IW' )`, which is always a Monday (and is independent of the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_TERRITORY` settings - unlike using `TO_CHAR` to find the day of the week):

```
SELECT day
FROM   ( 
  SELECT DATE '2017-06-21' + LEVEL - 1 as day
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY DATE '2017-06-21' + LEVEL - 1 <= DATE '2017-07-21'
)
WHERE day - TRUNC( day, 'IW' ) IN ( 2, 4 );
```

**Update**:

Adding in bind parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CHAIRA"."PR_SAVEROOMS"(
  v_return OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  INIDATE IN VARCHAR2,
  ENDDATE IN VARCHAR2,
  DAYS IN NUMBER
)
AS
  v_error                  EXCEPTION;
  v_notificacion           t_notificacion;
  v_wednesdays_and_fridays SYS.ODCIDATELIST;  
BEGIN
  SELECT day
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_wednesdays_and_fridays
  FROM   ( 
    SELECT TO_DATE(iniDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + LEVEL - 1 as day
    FROM   DUAL
    CONNECT BY TO_DATE(iniDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + LEVEL - 1 <= TO_DATE(endDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  )
  WHERE day - TRUNC( day, 'IW' ) IN ( 2, 4 );

  v_notificacion := t_notificacion('notificacion','Información','Mensaje por defecto');
  OPEN v_return FOR
    SELECT v_notificacion(1) "_TIPO",
           v_notificacion(2) "_TITULO",
           v_notificacion(3) "_MENSAJE"
    FROM DUAL;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN v_error THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20333,v_notificacion(1)||'*'||v_notificacion(2)||'*'||v_notificacion(3)||'*');
    ROLLBACK;
END; 
/
```

Comment: If i replace the initial & final dates for parameter it´ll cause an error. how can i solve this? @MT0

Comment: @HARRY Updated.

Comment: I HAD UPDATE MY POST, BUT STILL CAUSES ERROR.. @MT0

Comment: @HARRY You do not need to shout. Updated - you aren't doing anything with the values but it should compile.

Answer (score 0):

As we are using **sysdate** if you run the script in different days , you should adjust something

```
select * from (SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE + (ROWNUM*7)) dt
  FROM DUAL 
  CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 100 ) where dt between '21-JUN-17 00:00:00' and '21-JUL-17 00:00:00'
   ;
```

Comment: This does not filter for Wednesdays and Fridays only (and is dependent on the dates being in a future date range).